# Display a TextView 5dp from the bottom

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

```
Android Studio 0.3.7
```

Hello,

I have the following `TextView` that is on a `Linearlayout (vertical)`.

I want to display the `TextView` just about `5dp` from the bottom of the layout. However, I can't seem to do that.

I have played around with the different properties of the `android:layout_marginBottom` and some other properties as well.

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Sign Up with StarBucks"
        android:id="@+id/tv_signup"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#380aff"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the correct property to set to get the `Textview` positioned from the bottom of the layout.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >
    //other controls define here
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use this

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am new to Android, and I didn't know about nested layouts, seems this will be very useful when laying out controls.

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Setting the layout gravity to bottom, shifts all the controls to start from the bottom. This is not really what I want. As I have other controls position in the center. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The textView have to be child of the RelativeLayout then You can use `alignParentBottom="true"` and set marignBottom

Comment: Linear layout is the best layout for what I am doing with the controls.

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:layout_gravity` to `bottom`

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
<TextView 
     android:padding_bottom="5dp"
     android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
     ........ />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`
or else if you want your textview to be horizontally center then you may set

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```